# What does this[var_name] = 12; do in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Today I've seen code on w3resource and I was thinking what it does:

```js
var var_name = 'abcd';
var n = 120;
this[var_name] = n;
console.log(this[var_name]);
// the OUTPUT : 120

// This line was added to this example.
console.log(abcd);
```

Firstly I thought it's to change the variable value but when I type `var_name` in the console to get the value it gave me 'abcd'. Actually this is very confusing to me.

Comment: Don't do this, and don't use this resource any more.

Comment: `this` in the global scope refers to the window object. Variables you define in the global scope all are in the window object. So `this[var_name]=n` is the same as writing `var_name=n` in the global scope.

Comment: @Danmoreng *Variables you define in the global scope all are in the window object.* That's incorrect, in a couple of respects. First, it's only in the browser. Second, it's only for variables declared using `var`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript `this` always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. But since in the code the `this` is used globally it relates to the document level. So,

```
var var_name = 'abcd';
```

Creates a variable name `var_name` with value `abcd`. This is commonly used to create a variable.

But,

```
var n = 120;
this[var_name] = n;
```

Can be accessed when you make an object. We add properties to `this` when we want the properties to exist with the life of the object. We Use `var` for local variables.

Hence, `this[var_name]` and `var_name` are treated separately.

Comment: I'm completely unable to parse this answer. Functions don't have "owners", and whatever an owner is, that's not (necessarily) what `this` refers to. `this` used globally (in the browser) does not relate to the document level; it relates to the **window** level, which is something altogether different.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I've added comments to the lines. Hope this helps you to understand the code

```
var var_name = 'abcd'; //creates a new variable with the name var_name and the 
value 'abcd'
var n = 120; //creates a new variable with the name n and the value 120
this[var_name] = n; //add a new property with the value of var_name (abcd) to this and the value of n (120)
```